# Efficient algorithm for agents sharing energy with nearby agents only?

Tags: algorithm, netlogo

Soooo, I have a bunch of turtle agents who need to "share"/"receive" energy with one another. The idea is straightforward, within a group of turtles you take the average energy and move a small amount from those with more than average to those with less than average.

Totally trivial if you take the full group of turtles, but because turtles group themselves by location, the only way to fully compute all the sharing is to check for each turtle who is nearby. Then you ask all the turtles around them to add/subtract from their energies. It would be MUCH nicer to somehow do a linear time calculation, but I can't come up with any good way to do so. One possibility I considered is to pre-calculate the entire matrix of distances in advance so that finding nearby turtles doesn't require a call to "turtles in-radius X".

I'm looking for other implementation shortcuts that might cut down on processing time, or alternative ideas for sharing algorithms. Thanks!

Comment: Your description of the problem is inadequate. You must define the costs of communication and computation. Must all communication be pairwise?  What is the meaning of "distance?" Etc, etc, etc. Then it _might_ be possible to recommend something other than the trivial algorithm of having one node collect complete information about all others and send out directives to them about what to do.

Comment: You might get more help if you abstract the description of your problem away from turtles and energy.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. I hope it doesn't get downvoted too much for being somewhat open-ended. slater, not sure if you're familiar with NetLogo, but a turtle is just an agent with a location, and I think "energy" is just a number here, so the question actually is already almost entirely abstract. Gene, similar comment: in NetLogo turtle have location and "distance" is built-in as meaning ordinary Euclidean distance on the plane.

Comment: Thanks Seth for clarifying this.

Answer (score 1):

I know you wanted to avoid `in-radius`, but it's actually pretty efficient for small radii. Thus, without knowing more, I think this would be the simplest way of getting the effect that you want:

```
ask turtles [
  set energy mean [ energy ] of turtles in-radius d
]
```

This is not linear, but if `d` is small and you have less than, say, a thousand turtles, it will be plenty fast. It's flexible in that you don't have to precalculate the groups of turtles. It actually smooths the energies across space rather equalizes the energies within groups. Note that it is non-deterministic: what energy each turtle ends up with depends on the order the turtles run in. That shouldn't be a big deal, but if it is, you can fix it by having each turtle calculate the means and then have each turtle set their energies.

Alternatively, if you have a list of turtle-sets that contain each group, you can do:

```
foreach groups [
  let new-energy mean [ energy ] of ?
  ask ? [ set energy new-energy ]
]
```

This is linear, with the only downside being that you have to explicitly calculate the groups (they also need to be transitive: if turtle `a` and `b` are in the same group and turtle `b` and `c` are in the same group, `a` and `c` must also be in the same group). I'm happy to recommend strategies for calculating groups, but I need to know how the groups are defined.

Finally, if you have enough turtles so that there are less patches than turtles, you can do things like this:

```
ask patches [
  set mean-energy mean [ energy ] of turtles-here
]
diffuse mean-energy .5
ask turtles [
  set energy mean-energy
]
```

This is linear in the number of patches plus the number of turtles. It's nice since you don't have to explicitly define groups, and the rate of diffusion of energy is easily defined.

Comment: Bryan the last answer got me thinking and I think I'll be able to use that concept to make it work. Thanks a lot for the helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try dividing your surface (or space) into Quadtrees (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

Every time a turtle moves, you should calculate to which segments of quadtree it belongs and add it to some kind of list. Then when searching you only check the nearby nodes.

This way you will significantly reduce number of operations (from n^2)

Comment: Of course this is how you would do this when turtles are moving. If they're not, then precalculate that. Also if the turtles move very slowly, you can check their new position in quadtrees more rarely (like each fifth iteration).

Comment: NetLogo's `in-radius` is fairly efficient for small distances. In fact, it's more efficient than a quadtree if the number of patches in the radius is less than `log(n)` (where `n` is the number of turtles). Of course, that isn't usually the case, but it is usually fast enough

Comment: Thanks Michael for the idea! I had completely forgotten about quadtrees and other structures for organizing space.